# How make side bar appear first in moble?

Tags: wordpress

How can I make the sidebar appear fist before content in Twenty Eleven theme.

Now if I resize the browser sidebar goes to the end, I need add a sidebar to go First in Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` in your template file, and move it to the top. So, for example, when you look at the index.php, you get this:

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 */

get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">
```

Comment: I did. But after that it goes to the end of the page.